# Dynamic hours in the Time Schedule documentation

Tags: optaplanner

I am reviewing the time schedule example to organize the times and room to a specific lesson. However, the time in the example is doing the assumption that each class is 1 hour. Where can I find more information in Optaplanner? if I decide to change the hour to a predefined duration such as 1 hour, 2.5 hours depending of the lesson. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [**the Conference Scheduling example**](https://www.optaplanner.org/learn/useCases/conferenceScheduling.html) in optaplanner-examples (!= optaplanner-quickstarts).

In that case a Talk (= Lesson) is assigned to a Timeslot and a Room, but each talk has a talkType (for example "conference talk", "lab", "deep dive", "lighting talk", etc) and each timeslot has a requiredTalkType.

For performance reasons, it uses "value range from entity" (instead of "value range from solution"), so that requiredTalkType becomes a build-in hard constraints instead of an actual hard constraint.

Also read the docs section **Assigning to time** in the Design Patterns chapter. This is just the tip of the iceberg: there are other patterns too. Conference scheduling still uses the "timeslot pattern", because the "timegrain pattern" is often slow.